# How to edit the nodes of the built-in robot

Tags: webots

I found that in the latest version of webots (2019a), it is not possible to edit the model tree nodes of the built-in robots. They seem to be encapsulated and there are no Children nodes. I hope to learn modeling with examples of built-in robots, but in previous versions (version 7.0.3) it was editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robot definitions are indeed most of the time encapsulated in what we call a PROTO nodes.

- PROTO description: https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/proto
- Tutorial on how to create your own PROTO node: https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-7-your-first-proto

But you can remove this 'encapsulation' simply by right-clicking in the scene tree on the node and selecting 'Convert to Base Node(s)'. This will completely 'unprototize' the node and you will be able to see the complete hierarchy (including the 'children' nodes)